# Flutter DropdownButtonFormField not showing selected item

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dropdown, flutter-state

Using DropdownButtonFormField element to show a lists of cities. It works fine on change event and show the selected item on change event. Issue is that once I try to show selected item from set state its not working. Although state is successfully set and working.

Here is my DropdownButtonFormField code:-

```
              DropdownButtonFormField(
                value: _city,
                onChanged: (String newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    _city = newValue;
                  });
                },
                // initialValue: 'Male',
                items: ['Ajman','Al Ain','Dubai','Fujairah','Ras Al Khaimah', 'Sharjah', 'Ajman','Umm Al Quwain']
                    .map((cityTitle) => DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: cityTitle, child: Text("$cityTitle")))
                    .toList(),
              )
```

I set _city in InitState

```
@override
void initState() {
  setFilters();
  super.initState();
}

setFilters(){
   setState(() {
     _city = "Dubai";
   });
}
```

But it's not showing selected value. How can I fix that ?
Meanz when I want to set value of _city from initState its not working

Comment: The value of the `DropdownMenuItem` is set to `gender`! is this a typo or is it related to the problem? Shouldn't the value be also `cityTitle` ?

Comment: yeah its cityTitle just type error on stack....i update question

Comment: Is DropdownButtonFormField in dialog?

Comment: this happened to me after I updated the flutter. Seems like they are talking about it. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56725